# how to insert or update records in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a bulk list of employees and their related information from other tables. I want to create a leave roster at once for all of them and also have an option to select a single employee and insert or update the respective roaster record. I have some codes here please assist how to accomplish that.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Employee;

use App\LeaveSetting;
use App\Roaster;
use App\User;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use DB;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class LeaveRoasterController extends Controller
{
    public function prepare(){
        $employees = DB::table('users')
            ->leftJoin('job_details', 'users.id', '=', 'job_details.user_id')
            ->leftJoin('terminations', 'terminations.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
            ->leftJoin('departments', 'departments.id', '=','job_details.department')
            ->where('termination_status', '!=', 3)
            ->select('users.id AS employee_id', 'users.name AS name', 'departments.department AS department')
            ->orderBy('name', 'ASC')
            ->get();

        return view('employee.roaster', compact('employees'));
    }

    public function submitRoaster(Request $request){

        $roaster_exist = Roaster::all()->where('leave_year', '=', financial_year())->count();

        if ($roaster_exist > 0){
            DB::table('roasters')->where('leave_year', '=', financial_year())->delete();

        }
        foreach ($user_id = $request->user_id as $key => $value) {

            if ($user_id[$key] != '') {

                $from = $request->start_date[$key];
                $end  = $request->end_date[$key];

                $data = [
                    'user_id' => $value,
                    'leave_year' => financial_year(),
                    'leave_setting_id' => 1,
                    'start_date' => $from,
                    'end_date' => $end,
                    'created_at' => Carbon::now(),
                    'updated_at' => Carbon::now()];

                DB::table('roasters')->insert($data);
            }
        }

        flash('You have submitted leave roaster successfully!');
        return back();
    }
```

Comment: why don't you use model to insert or update record this is very bad way to use laravel

Comment: If you want to do raw `PHP` then do `RAW PHP` if you want to do `Laravel` then do `Laravel`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **`updateOrInsert`** method...

```
$query = DB::table("roasters")
            ->updateOrInsert(
            [
                'id' => $update_id, // pass your update id else empty
            ],
            [
                'user_id' => $value,
                'leave_year' => financial_year(),
                'leave_setting_id' => 1,
                'start_date' => $from,
                'end_date' => $end,
                'created_at' => Carbon::now(),
                'updated_at' => Carbon::now()
            ]);
```

Comment: thank you so much Anthony Jack,you saved me a lot!!!